# Error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Tags: swift, swiftui

[Swift/SwiftUI] Problem with call other method from file "ScheduleManagementView.swift".
Error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments".

Error appears in string 35.

Already tried to replace NavigationLink with Button, remove '$', add '$'.
Can't get how to fix that.

Part of the code from file "HelperMainMenu.swift":

```
struct ScheduleManagementView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    @State private var selectedEmployee = ""
    @State private var startTime = Date()
    @State private var endTime = Date()
    @State private var showScheduleList = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var schedules: [ShiftSchedule] = []'

   //var body: some View {...
    
    NavigationLink(destination: ScheduleManagementView(schedules: $schedules)) {
                            Image(systemName: "calendar")
                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                        }
                        
    NavigationLink(destination: ExpensesCounterView(schedules: $schedules)) {
                            Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle")
                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                        }
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, could you post the init for ScheduleManagementView and/or its property declarations?

Comment: `struct ScheduleManagementView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    @State private var selectedEmployee = ""
    @State private var startTime = Date()
    @State private var endTime = Date()

    @State private var showScheduleList = false
    @State private var showAlert = false

    @State private var schedules: [ShiftSchedule] = []'`

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there instead of posting it as a comment, it is very hard to read. Anyway, all your properties has initial values so no init is created. Do you want to pass `schedules` to the view, if so then you need to declare the corresponding property in the view as `@Binding`

Comment: Sorry for posting it like this. I added this part to the question. To be honest, i'm newbie and not sure how it works for 100%. The idea to have 2 navigations, one to method "ScheduleManagementView" that creates schedules, second to method "ExpensesCounterView" that counts salary from created schedules (so 1st and 2nd are connected, maybe that's why it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure, why would you call the same view from this view, but beside this, the `@State private var schedules: [ShiftSchedule] = []` is **private**, so you can't pass value to this when you try to call `ScheduleManagementView(schedules: $schedules)`. And you won't need the $ sign.